# Anywhere - Field validation

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Working on Work Execution app (v 7.5.2). In MAM, Field having datatype as INTEGER (4) but when I enter values "1234567890123456789' in Anywhere, it doesn't throw error instantly but after saving, It throws "Database error number -4461 has occurred when operating on WORKLOG :  WorkLog ID=1234. Report the error to the owner of the deployment."

Either User should warn immediately after entered or Need to restrict the MaxLength to enter in TEXTBOX. How to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put some validate javascript code on the dataChange event for this field to validate that less than 4 characters were input.  You can also open a PMR as this seems like a limitation that we would address in a future release.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Is this limitation in 7.6 version also ?

Comment: it is, this isn't improved in 7.6